# -notmatch operator not giving desired result in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to check if a statement is there is file or not. For example, i have a file named File1.txt which has "As per your request, we have deleted your record".
I using line below to get the content from the file
`$data=Get-Content -Path $Home\Desktop\File1.txt` and then i am trying to check if this file has "As per your request" or not

```
if($data -notmatch "As per your request")
{
Write-Host "Not matched"
}
else
{
Write-Host "Matched"
}
```

When i am running this script, it returns all the time "Not matched". I do not understand why it is happening. Please help me with. I know this is very basic but can not understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-Content` returns the content *line-by-line*, so the `$data` variable contains an array of strings.

When applied to an array, `-notmatch` starts acting like a *filter* instead of a boolean operator:

```
$array = @(
  'a'
  'b'
  'c'
)

$result = $array -notmatch 'b'
$result 
# a
# c
```

After running the example above, you'll find that `$result` contains the strings `'a'` and `'c'` - because they were the items in the array that did not match the pattern `'b'`.

Instead, you'll want to use `-match` to look for any occurrence of the substring and then negate the result of that expression:

```
if(-not($data -match "As per your request"))
{
  # if "As per your request" was NOT found, the expression will evaluate to `$null`, and `-not($null)` is equivalent to `-not($false)`, ie, `$true`
  Write-Host "Not matched"
}
else
{
  Write-Host "Matched"
}
```